# How to run a Django's application server on a VPS server

Tags: django, vps, ubuntu-20.04

I have an application that should run via VPS terminal-based so that the web app can be online permanently.
The command: `python manage.py runserver 173.249.8.237:8000` should be executed via the VPS terminal because when I use putty via my laptop, whenever I switch off my putty software via my laptop, the application won't be accessible.
Please, suggest to me a way open a terminal in order to run the Django application server.
Or, is there any method that can allow me to my Django web application on VPS?

Thanks in advence

Comment: Could try running the command in a screen https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-screen-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that.

`runserver` according [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver)

> DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone
> through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s
> gonna stay. We’re in the business of making web frameworks, not web
> servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production
> environment is outside the scope of Django.)

You need to configure your Django application to run in production environments. You change choose docker for that.

Or simple running with `gunicorn`.

1. Access your VPS through SSH or Putty.
2. Copy your application code inside VPS
3. Configure your application to run with [gunicorn](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-scale-and-secure-a-django-application-with-docker-nginx-and-let-s-encrypt) or [docker](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-scale-and-secure-a-django-application-with-docker-nginx-and-let-s-encrypt)
4. Access your VPS address in your browser.
5. And turn of the DEBUG mode, by setting `DEBUG=False`

Comment: And turn off the debug mode in production!